# Making a Element White Once Clicked, and Red Once Clicked Again

Tags: javascript, html

I have a question about having an element turn white, and red once clicked again. I use chrome. Also, I don't understand how I make that happen by a bit, so I wish to receive a detailed reply.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
        var color = document.querySelectorAll('h1')
        color.onclick = function(){
          if (this.style.backgroundColor == 'red') {
            this.style.backgroundColor = 'white'
            this.style.color = 'white'
          }
          if (this.style.backgroundColor == 'blue') {
            this.style.backgroundColor = 'white'
            this.style.color = 'white'
          }
          if (this.style.backgroundColor == 'white') {
            this.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
            this.style.color = 'red'
          }

        }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

(edit)I am sorry that I hadn't added a snippet, and I am adding this one with the edit. I wish to have an even more detailed explanation, thank you. I have tried to search on google, to search on this website, and to ask this question.(edit)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to work out exactly what you're trying to do without some sample code, but if I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you're trying to alternate a background colour on click.

First, you want to select the element on the page. Then apply a click handler. Inside of this click handler, you want to check the background colour in a conditional with the **[`style` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)**. If the colour is red, you set it to white. If the colour is not red, you set it to red.

This can be seen in the following example:

```js
var example = document.getElementById('example');
example.onclick = function() {
  if (this.style.backgroundColor == 'red') {
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'white'
  }
   else {
     this.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
   }
}
```

```html
<div id="example">Text</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Is there any way to do this to all elements?

Comment: Yes. use [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Comment: Instead of what?